Return statement isnt working and is giving an error in react js
I was writing this code where I am making some Modals so I wrote this code
import { useContext } from "react"
import { ModalContext } from "../ModalProvider"
import { CreatePlaygroundModal } from "./CreatePlaygroundModal";

export const Modal = () => {
    const modalFeatures = useContext(ModalContext);

    return (
      <>{modalFeatures.activeModal === "CREATE_PLAYGROUND" && <CreatePlaygroundModal />}</>          
    );
}

Here the line is giving me an error
return (
      <>{modalFeatures.activeModal === "CREATE_PLAYGROUND" && <CreatePlaygroundModal />}</>          
    );

I dont know why this simple part isnt working
Also I am a beginner so accept my apologize if it is too petty
The Error is
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'activeModal')
    at Modal (Modal.js:9:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:15486:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20103:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21626:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27490:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26596:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26505:1)

I tried rewriting this part but it didnt help
Here is some more info to check from-
index.js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Modal } from "../../Providers/Modals/Modal.js";
import "./index.scss";
import logo from "./logo.png";
import {RightComponent} from "./RightComponent/index.js"
import { ModalContext } from "../../Providers/ModalProvider.js";

export const HomeScreen = () => {
    const modalFeatures = useContext(ModalContext);

    const openCreatePlayGroundModal = () =>{
        modalFeatures.openModal("CREATE_PLAYGROUND") 
    }
    return(
        <div className="home-container">
            <div className="left-container">
            <div className="items-container">
            <img className="left-logo" src={logo} alt="Logo" />
            <h2>Version 0.0.1(Beta)</h2>
            <br></br>
            <button className="left-button" onClick={openCreatePlayGroundModal}><span class="material-symbols-outlined">chat</span> Switch To Chat(Coming Soon!)</button>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="right-container">
                {/* <h1 >Right wala</h1> */}
                <RightComponent />
                <Modal />
            </div>
        </div>  
    );
};

Here is the ModalProvider.js file from which it is taking and updating info
import { createContext, useState } from "react";
import { CreatePlaygroundModal } from "./Modals/CreatePlaygroundModal";

export const ModalContext = createContext();
 


export const ModalProvider = ({children}) => {

    const [modalType, setModalType] = useState(null);
 
    const closeModal = () => {
        setModalType(null)
    };
   
    const modalFeatures = {
        openModal:setModalType,
        closeModal,
        activeModal: modalType
  }

    // const modalTypes = {
    //     ["create-playground"]: CreatePlaygroundModal
    // }

    // const openModal = (type) => {
    //     setModalType(type)
    // };

    console.log({modalType});


    // const [modalType, setModalType] = useState(null);


    
 return (
    <ModalContext.Provider Value={modalFeatures}>
        {children}  
    </ModalContext.Provider>
 )
} 


The error is not directly related to return, that just happens to be the line where the error happens. The error is caused because modalFeatures is undefined. So that means useContext(ModalContext) is returning undefined. Your real problem probably lies there - why is useContext(ModalContext) returning undefined

Usually this happens because of an incorrect or missing context provider. Do some debugging around that yourself and then come back and [edit] your question with those details

@BrianThompson, I am new to coding so I cant really find, I managed to get the immediate error away but when I click the button that should summon the model it gives this error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'openModal') i did attach the other two files required to find the problem and it would mean the world to me if you could help me out..

Typo?  Value={modalFeatures} - The value prop should be lowercase?

@David it worked! Thank you so much!!

@DivyanshPathak if that was the solution, you really should not mark one of these answers as accepted. They did not actually solve your problem and could mislead future readers of this question

You should check modalFeatures containing activeModal.
Rewrite this code to
return (
      <>{modalFeatures?.activeModal === "CREATE_PLAYGROUND" && <CreatePlaygroundModal />}</>          
    );


It's irresponsible to suggest using nullsafe when you don't know if it's valid for modelFeatures to be null. 9/10 times doing this will remove the error without actually finding the bug. Doing this just hides the bug even more.

This gets the immediate error away but when I click the button that should summon the model it gives this error  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'openModal') also i have attached more data for you too understand the challenge easily

Use this code and check modal (ModalContext) In your code
return (
      <>{modalFeatures?.activeModal === "CREATE_PLAYGROUND" &&<CreatePlaygroundModal />}</>          
    );

